# Sharing an instantiated class among multiple objects in C#

Tags: c#, wpf

I currently have a class which I instantiate when I start my program. The class itself will create a new thread and begin to search for broadcasts from routers.

I have other windows, other then MainWindow, which needs to be able to access the data stored within the instance of this class. However, I'm not sure as to how the other windows can reference this data.

Is there some other way I can store the instance of this class so that it is accessible application wide? I need it to start right when the rest of the application starts, so it seemed logical (to me) to have the class be instantiated in the first window.

```
namespace Lalu_WPF
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        // data storage for program
        public FindRouter finder = new FindRouter();

        public MainWindow()
        {
......
```

Comment: will [Singleton pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) work?

Comment: everytime someone makes Singleton tester kill a kitteh

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't make Singleton (notice the capital letter). It is error prone in multiple threads environments(muttable Singletons) and bad for testing.

What are your requirements?

Do you have to have one object in one application or one object in whole CLR?

I bet the first one.

Make an object in your App class (App.xaml.cs) and then acces it via getter

```
App MyApplication = ((App)Application.Current);
MyApplication.Router;
```

Comment: It's only error prone in multi-threaded environments if you don't make it thread safe.  I don't think that's a good reason not to use it.

Comment: It's good reason to use it carefully. Also, it's difficult to test. Have to bulid a mock object when you cannot override it?

Comment: This is far better than a singleton.

Comment: Simple, easy for me to implement, provided an example. For a prototype, it will work -- although the other solutions presented were quite helpful. I didn't know the term "Singleton" -- although I had seen that technique used previously. Thanks again.

Answer (score 4):

[Don't](http://accu.org/index.php/journals/1400) use a [Singleton](http://tech.puredanger.com/2007/07/03/pattern-hate-singleton/), it makes [unit testing hard](http://code.google.com/p/google-singleton-detector/wiki/WhySingletonsAreControversial) and [your code surprising](http://sebastian-bergmann.de/archives/882-Testing-Code-That-Uses-Singletons.html).

Give classes which need access to an instance the instance.  That means that every class which needs this single instance should accept either by a constructor argument or setter.  Whoever creates the class is then in charge of supplying the dependency.  This is called [Dependency Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection).

Comment: I'd use this one over all other suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

You could make the class a singleton and this way you could access this same instance across the entire application.  You can see an example on the msdn website [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx)

Comment: Singleton is a bad pattern, or should I say easy pattern. I think it is too often used in bad cases. Moreover, an alternative such as passing the instance into the constructor would make it much more testable than a singleton .

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a Program class? In the Windows Forms projects that I do, variables such as that go in Program `public` `static` `readonly` members or in `public` `static` properties with `get` only.

Answer (score 0):

What you're talking about sounds like the Singleton design pattern. You could create a singleton object, a static class, or (what I like) a Monostate object (an object that encapsulates the static class or single instance) , something like this:

```
public class SingletonWidget
{
    private static readonly Implementation SingleInstance ;

    public void DoSomething( int someValue )
    {
        SingleInstance.DoSomething( someValue ) ;
        return ;
    }
    public int SomeProperty
    {
        get
        {
            return SingleInstance.SomeProperty ;
        }
        set
        {
            SingleInstance.SomeProperty = value ;
        }
    }

    static SingletonWidget()
    {
        SingleInstance = new Implementation() ;
        return ;
    }

    private class Implementation
    {
        public void DoSomething( int someValue )
        {
            // ...
        }
        public int SomeProperty { get ; private set ; }
    }

}
```

Usage looks like normal object instantation:

```
SingletonWidget foo = new SingletonWidget() ;

foo.DoSomething(3) ;
```

but under the covers, there's just a single instance hanging around. Changing from a static class or singleton is trivial as only the wrapper needs to change. Building stubs or mocks is pretty easy, too.

It makes it easy to

Answer (score 0):

Try a DI framework or some less complex implementation of a service locator. That will allow you to provide the instance where it is needed throughout your app without hardcoding in a singleton, which is then painful to write tests around.

I know that [Ninject](http://ninject.org) at least provides support for single instances application-wide. I haven't used it in a WPF application but I can't see why not.

As a basic example of a service locator you could do something like the following. I've called the shared class `Foo`:

```
public interface IFoo { ... }
public class Foo { ... }

public class ServiceLocator
{
    IFoo _foo = new Foo();
    public IFoo GetFoo() { return _foo; }
}

public class DependsOnFoo
{
    public IFoo Foo = ServiceLocator.GetFoo();
    ...
}
```

`DependsOnFoo.Foo` is the shared instance of `Foo` by default but when writing automated tests you could swap it out with a stub or mock:

```
var testTarget = new DependsOnFoo();
testTarget.Foo = mockFooImplementation;
// now testTarget isn't bound to the Foo implementation
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your question is how to store a reference to your finder rather than how to create it. If this is the case I would suggest using `IDictionary Application.Current.Properties` property, which is nothing but a collection of application-scope properties. At startup you can create your object and store a reference to it like this:

```
Application.Current.Properties["finder"] = new FindRouter();
```

Then, in any place of your program you can access it like

```
FindRouter finder = (FindRouter)Application.Current.Properties["finder"];
```

Hope this helps.